# Making Python module import unambiguous

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, importerror

Consider you have the following project structure:

```
FooProject
├── foo_components
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── foo1.py
├── utils
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── utils1.py
├── tests
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── foo_components
│        ├── __init__.py
│        └── test_foo1.py
│   ├── utils
│        └── __init__.py
│        └──test_utils1.py
|
└── __init__.py
```

My question is as follows:
Consider you are in scope of `test_foo1.py` file
in order to test the spectacular foo component called :`foo1`.
You want to import the following:

`from foo_components.foo1 import Foo1`

But then you get an error because of ambiguity:
`Module not found for foo_components.foo1`.

This is probably because in your scope `foo_components` module is referred to as the path of modules:
`tests.foo_components`. ( meaning it doesn't have `foo1`, more likely `test_foo1`).

How would you solve such a case elegantly?
Can I cause python to understand which python module I'm referring to, seems like it automatically make assumptions as relative import, and not to the top-level module.

In your solution please avoid suggesting importing with relative imports, far as I know its not bad practice, meaning something like `from ../../xyz import foo1`.
I thought of changing `foo_component` to not be same name also under tests, but I don't like this solution either, I guess there is some reasonable way.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can try importing it specifically from the project root library.
Like this:
From FooProject.foo_components import foo1.py

I’m this case it won’t go to the other foo_components, and if you want to go there than you can do:
From FooProject.tests.foo_components import test_foo1.py